# Has there ever been a country that implemented whitelist-based internet censorship?

Tags: firewalls, vpn, tor, whitelist, censorship

We hear time and time again of countries censoring internet traffic by blocking IP Ranges.

Without getting into the politics of it, let's take for example China's Great Firewall. Even though it is not the most oppressive of firewalls, it still seems to be a constant cat-and-mouse game of VPN server's IP addresses getting blocked and VPN hosting companies moving to different IPs. When technologies altogether such as OpenVPN get blocked, modifications are made to the protocol to allow the traffic to pass undetected.

With so much effort going into maintaining these firewalls, it might almost be worthwhile to create a list of every legitimate service IP that is used. Has a government ever experimented with whitelist-based censorship?

Answer (score 3):

North Korea comes to mind. Most North Korean users only have access to [Kwangmyong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwangmyong_(network)) national network controlled by the government. This can be viewed as an extreme case of a whitelist-based approach to censorship.

Comment: That Wikipedia link has a link to the "National Intranet" article which just about answers my question. To sum it up North Korea, Cuba, Myanmar, and possibly in the future Iran have one.

Answer (score 1):

Turkey has that, but as an option. It is called "[çocuk profili](https://internet.btk.gov.tr/guvenli-internet-hizmeti)" (Turkish for *child profile*).